# Extract pages from bigger PDF with qpdf, preserving also left bookmarks

Tags: pdf

I use this to extract PDF range of pages from a bigger PDF input file

```
qpdf --empty --pages input.pdf 1051-1118 -- output.pdf
```

It's working nicely, however, the left menu (bookmarks) disappeared.

Is there a way to preserve it?

Also I noticed that all references (document local links) are broken.
For example in original doc was a link to page 1055 (inside my range) and after extraction I would expect to be re-written to page 2 in my new document.

Is there a way to use qpdf in a more advanced way to do that?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the range of options for `qpdf` by opening a terminal and typing `qpdf --help`.

This is the Manpage for the tool

[image]